# New Activity not opening on push notification click

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

I have a class `Home.java` which runs first on opening the app when I open it to check if the user is logged in or not.

```
public class Home extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is when I'm getting a notification for this app, it is starting from LogIn activity instead of going to HomeActivity.
I'm aware that if I want to open a specific activity from a notification, I need to specify getIntent() in the launcher activity, but I don't have any launcher activity. 
When I try to implement getIntent() in Home.java class the method is not getting imported since it doesn't extends the Activity class.
Any help!

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Restaurants")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setSound(uri);     //applying default notification sound to the notification


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("Restaurants", "demo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want open an activity when click to Notification then use a code like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Restaurants")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setSound(uri);     //applying default notification sound to the notification

    //Create an intent to gom HomeActivity 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("Restaurants", "demo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```